# Problema al instalar un paquete distribuible PYTHON

Tags: python, windows

Estoy aprendiendo a crear paquetes distribuibles en python. Cree uno simple que contiene un modulo con funciones aritméticas simples. Pero cuando lo voy a instalar en la consola de windows me salta el siguiente error y no se como solucionarlo. Revisé muchas veces que el nombre del paquete esté bien escrito e intente varias veces pero me sigue saltando lo mismo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné simplemente utilizando el windows powershell en lugar de la consola. volví a crear el paquete y lo instale TODO EN EL POWERSHELL